# Remove the need to iterate the list for every element

Tags: java, iterator

I constructed a fairly simple program which takes information from a `.txt` file and puts it in a list, sorts it, and then it removes duplicates by putting it in a `TreeSet`.

If you look at `countInstance()` and how it is called, you will see that for every iteration of the `TreeSet` the method is run and then it iterates the list `dataToSplit` multiple times. I believe it iterates the list 30 times in this specific case.

**The Question**
Is there a way I can remove the need to iterate the list so many times and yet achieve the same results?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TallyCounter {
    private void tallyCount(File commaSeperated) {
        List<String> dataToSplit = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> set;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(commaSeperated));
            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tempArray = currentLine.split(",");
                for(String s : tempArray) {
                    dataToSplit.add(s.replaceAll("\t", "").replaceAll("\n", "").trim());
                }
            }

            br.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dataToSplit.sort(new AlphanumComparator());
        set = new TreeSet<String>(dataToSplit);


        System.out.println("String  Tally  Count");
        for(String s : set) {
            System.out.println(countInstance(s, dataToSplit));
        }
    }

    private String countInstance(String s, List<String> l) {
        int count = 0;

        for(String temp : l) {
            if(s.equals(temp)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        int rSpace = (10 - count) / 2;

        String repeated = new String(new char[count]).replace("\0", "|");
        String space = new String(new char[rSpace]).replace("\0", " ");

        return " " + s + " " + space + repeated + " " + space  + Integer.toString(count);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TallyCounter tC = new TallyCounter();
        tC.tallyCount(new File("src/txt.txt"));
    }
}
```

---

**Extra details**

*AlphanumComparator.java*

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator<Object>
{
    private final boolean isDigit(char ch)
    {
        return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
    }

    /** Length of string is passed in for improved efficiency (only need to calculate it once) **/
    private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker)
    {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(marker);
        chunk.append(c);
        marker++;
        if (isDigit(c))
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (!isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        } else
        {
            while (marker < slength)
            {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        if (!(o1 instanceof String) || !(o2 instanceof String))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        String s1 = (String)o1;
        String s2 = (String)o2;

        int thisMarker = 0;
        int thatMarker = 0;
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();

        while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length)
        {
            String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
            thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

            String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
            thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

            // If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically
            int result = 0;
            if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0)))
            {
                // Simple chunk comparison by length.
                int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
                result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
                // If equal, the first different number counts
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++)
                    {
                        result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                        if (result != 0)
                        {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
            }

            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }

        return s1Length - s2Length;
    }
}
```

*txt.txt*

```
5.00,   5.14,   5.01,   4.90,   5.02,   5.18,   5.04,   5.07,   4.95,   5.05
5.05,   4.82,   4.97,   5.04,   4.98,   5.12,   5.08,   4.96,   5.02,   4.93
5.12,   5.04,   5.13,   4.94,   5.06,   5.00,   4.92,   5.17,   5.08,   4.99
5.07,   5.15,   5.01,   4.95,   5.11,   5.22,   5.08,   4.86,   4.97,   5.14
5.03,   5.14,   5.06,   4.88,   4.96,   5.04,   4.96,   5.09,   4.93,   5.03
```

---

*Foot Note*

I apologise for how strange the output looks when it is run. That is only because I have yet too implement a `JTable` to store the information

Comment: I find myself lost as to what you're trying to accomplish and what format your input is.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question as it has already been answered but there's no need to count the frequency of an item in a list. The collections framework already provides a method for this: Collections.frequency. Not that you should you use it in this case though.

Comment: @Renatols Thank you for the info but I was aware of the method. The problem with using it is it works by iterating the list like mine does so it may be slightly more efficient than my version but not drastically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `HashMap<String,Integer> countMap` and iterate through the strings once. With each `temp` you'll find, add 1 to the respective value `countMap.get(temp)` in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a [hash set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of a tree set. A hash allows you to get directly at the data you want instead of iterating through all the members. It has constant insert and query time. Also, if you want to associate each string with a number of instances that it appears, you could use a hash map instead of a set, and map the strings to `Integer`.

It's not the easiest to follow what you are doing. You were very brief in your description and did not comment your code; I suggest you remedy both of those problems. It took several minutes to analyze your code and understand what you were trying to do and how you were trying to do it. You'll get more help if we can understand the question immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would use instead of the `HashMap<String, Integer>` a `HashMap<Double, Integer>`

```
private void tallyCount(File commaSeperated) {
   HashMap<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(commaSeperated));
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tempArray = currentLine.split(",");
            for(String s : tempArray) {
                double value = Double.parseDouble(s);
                if (map.containsKey(value)) {
                    map.replace(value, map.get(value) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(value, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        br.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    map.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                  .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "|" + e.getValue()));
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TallyCounter tC = new TallyCounter();
    tC.tallyCount(new File("src/txt.txt"));
}
```